# PHP RSS script validating issue

Tags: php, rss

I am working on a script that will dynamically create an RSS Feed. Below is a simplified version of my code:

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");


    $rssfeed = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>';
    $rssfeed .= '<rss version="2.0">';
    $rssfeed .= '<channel>';
    $rssfeed .= '<title>My RSS feed</title>';
    $rssfeed .= '<link>http://www.mywebsite.com</link>';
    $rssfeed .= '<description>This is an example RSS feed</description>';
    $rssfeed .= '<language>en-us</language>';
    $rssfeed .= '<copyright>Copyright (C) 2009 mywebsite.com</copyright>';
    $rssfeed .= '<item>';
    $rssfeed .= '<title>Title</title>';
    $rssfeed .= '<description>This is a description</description>';
    $rssfeed .= '<link>www.google.com</link>';
    $rssfeed .= '<pubDate></pubDate>';
    $rssfeed .= '</item>';

    $rssfeed .= '</channel>';
    $rssfeed .= '</rss>';
    echo $rssfeed
?>
```

The output is fine, the structure seems ok. I testing the RSS feed in 'The Old Reader' by adding a subscription (see below).

[image]

I go to the validator and this message appears: It looks like this is a web page, not a feed. `I looked for a feed associated with this page, but couldn't find one. Please enter the address of your feed to validate.`

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: do you use function `header` before any output ?

Comment: i am at the top... second line.